# How do I loop through a list from dconf in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to read the list of Gnome Terminal profiles from dconf

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list
['b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9', '1a3bb41a-5de6-4a23-af30-e70b4b8e5230', 'afa18dee-db51-42b6-b15d-cc35a5738932', '69a27e59-4bc4-4a9c-ba5c-1201ebdb9841']
```

and then loop through that remaining list. Is there a sane way to do that without munging with `tr`? Currently I've got:

```
for PROFILE in $( dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list|tr -d "[],'");
do
    dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:${PROFILE}/word-char-exceptions '@ms "-,.;/:?%&#_=+@~·"'
done
```

but that seems a little gross. It happens in this case that I know that the set of `[],'` won't be in the values, but that's not universally true. (This list happens to be UUIDs — lower-case hex separated by dashes — but not all lists will be.) Is there a better way to actually *interpret* the square-bracket list syntax given here rather than working around it?

Comment: Matt, you can try to use jq. (json command line processor)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm open to that (provide an answer? It's not obvious offhand how to use this), although I'd prefer an entirely-bash solution.

Comment: Have you tried `| tr -cd 'a-z0-9- '`?

Comment: @mattdm, unfortunately jq do not like such strings :( Sorry

Comment: @Cyrus See edit. That isn't really any better than the "positive" `tr -d`.

Comment: You could try with `dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/ list` and remove first and last line (`list` and `default`) or `printf %s\\n 'from gi.repository import Gio' 'settings = Gio.Settings("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")' 'val = settings.get_strv("list")' 'for x in val:' '    print (x)' | python` (make sure you indent the `print(x)` - prepend four spaces as the comment block squeezes them).

Comment: Oh, if you get some annoying warnings with `pygi` try it like this: `printf %s\\n 'import warnings; warnings.simplefilter("ignore", Warning); from gi.repository import Gio' 'settings = Gio.Settings("org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList")' 'val = settings.get_strv("list")' 'for x in val:' '    print (x)' | python`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the comments you could use `jq`, which seems not to like `'`, but likes `"`, so

```
dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list | tr "'" '"' | jq
```

works as expected

```
[
  "b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-f897e3d979b9",
  "7b765e06-1bcc-4695-86d6-c2d391651ac2"
]
```

And the following will work, too

```
dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list | \
  tr "'" '"' | \
  jq '.[]' | \
  while read PROFILE; do
      echo "here's the logic for $PROFILE"
  done
```